# Structure as input for a Matlab function Block

Tags: matlab, structure, simulink

I have a, in my opinion, little problem using a Matlab-Function Block in a Simulink Model.
I want one of the inputs to be a structure. 
But that doesn't work so easily, I've come across 
suggestions on other semi-related problems, which tell about defining Simulink.Bus and so on, 
but to be honest I don't understand how this can be applied on my problem.

It seems simple:

Structure as input for a Matlab function Block

But I don't know how.

Sorry for the inconvenience.

Regards BZAD

Comment: In case you didn't find the answer from the links below here's how to do it: let's say you have a bus defined (could be done through the Bus Editor). When editing the Matlab Function block in Matlab's Editor there is a button saying 'Edit Data' in the toolbar. Click on it and you will see a list with all inputs and outputs. Select the input that has to be a structure and specify its data type to match a bus definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within Simulink you create a Bus signal using the Bus Creator Block.  This can then be fed into a MATLAB Function block, but only if an accompanying Simulink.Bus object is created in the Base Workspace.

See [Types of Structures in MATLAB Function Blocks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/types-of-structures-in-matlab-function-blocks.html) and [Create Structures in MATLAB Function Blocks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/create-structures-in-matlab-function-blocks.html) and the links off those pages for more information.

Comment: This was useful. But still, it doesn't work if you want to compile the whole Simulink Model. 
It gives me the following error:

Error using rsimgetrtp (line 105)
The block diagram 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' has a tunable parameter 'xxx' with data
type 'struct_kFoT1SdUa7eKY5TGqeywfH'. This data type is not supported by rsimgetrtp or in rapid accelerator
mode.

Error in xxxxxxxxx (line 35)
rtpstruct = rsimgetrtp(modelName);